# Create a function to clear a windows form(C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to clear a windows form using a C# function.

I know the method for clearing individual controls like

```
username.Clear();
password.Clear();
```

But, it is a large form an the clear function looks a bit awkward.

I found a code online which looks like this.

```
private void ClearFields(System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection collection)
{
    foreach (Control c in collection)
    {
        if (c.HasChildren)
            ClearFields(c.Controls);
        if (c is TextBox)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Text))
                c.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

But, for this code, the password field alone does not get cleared. I'm clearing "TextBox" controls alone. Do I have to specify any other control name for clearing a password field even though both are basically "TextBox" controls?

Comment: Is this code ok? Controls don't have Text property.

Comment: There is not a "password" control, just a TextBox.PasswordChar property set to a non null character.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But the code works fine for all other fields.

Comment: @Adriano Indeed. My mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get controls which are `TextBox` controls (or `TextBoxBase` if you want also to clear `MaskedTextBox` and `RichTextBox` also) and call their `Clear()` method:

```
private void ClearTextBoxes(ControlCollection controls)
{
    foreach (Control c in collection)
    {
        if (c.HasChildren)
        {
            ClearTextBoxes(c.Controls);
            continue;
        }

        TextBox tb = c as TextBox; // or TextBoxBase
        if (tb != null)
            tb.Clear();
    }
}
```

As @Adriano already pointed, 'password' controls are simple TextBoxes in WinForms

Comment: I'm sorry, but, it seems my function was pointing to a manual clear function which I had written earlier. My problem still exists, as this method still does not clear the password MessageBox. It just clears all other messageboxes fine, except the password one.

Comment: @MklRjv what messageboxes you are talking about? What is you custom function?

Comment: I have edited my question. Please find the updated code. The function which I had used to clear the form just clears all MessageBoxes manually. Like username.Clear() and password.Clear() and such.

Comment: @MklRjv I rolled back your edit - you just renamed my method to `ClearFields` and copy-pasted it to question. It adds no information and does not answer any of my questions

Comment: I'm really sorry about that previous comment, I meant TextBox, not MessageBox. Yes, I had modified my own function as per your suggestion. I had expected the function to identify and clear TextBoxes with the PasswordChar property set, which was my original question.

Comment: Just verified - TextBox with PasswordChar gets cleared as any other TextBox. I think you are clearing container which does not have this password TextBox

Comment: Tried using TextBox which doesnt seem to work, but, the TextBoxBase can be used and it clears password fields fine. Can you please check and comment?

Comment: @MklRjv if `TextBoxBase` works for you, then as I stated in my answer, you are using `MaskedTextBox` or `RichTextBox` for your 'password' control

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks, and sorry for the trouble. Newb in C# world you see.